# DRF getting list of objects in random order

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am going to get objects randomly but it shows one elements one more time. It should return all elements randomly without duplicate. Actually code I am using this it shows duplicates, I have pagination also because if user click show more button it shows one object one more time

```
class ModelModel(mdoels.Model):
   field_1 = mdoels.CharField(max_length=125)
   field_2 = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class ListObjectView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Model.objects.all().order_by('-pk').order_by('?')
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
```

I also wrote custom function that takes randomly but It returns one object not all of them

```
def get_random_objects():
    return random.randrange(1, Model.objects.all().count() + 1)

class ItemsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    #queryset = Model.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model.objects.all().filter(id=get_random_objects())
```

it only return one **Model** objects not all. How can I return all elements ordered randomly?

```
[<Model: Object_1>, <Model: Object_2>]
Internal Server Error: /product-list/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 457, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 468, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 199, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 38, in list
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 150, in filter_queryset
    queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 90, in filter_queryset
    filterset = self.get_filterset(request, queryset, view)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 31, in get_filterset
    filterset_class = self.get_filterset_class(view, queryset)
  File "venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py", line 64, in get_filterset_class
    assert issubclass(queryset.model, filterset_model), \
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Any help plz? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your filter is `id=...` so you're trying to get one specific id.

Comment: `random.randrange` will return only 1 value

Comment: `Model.objects.all().order_by('?')` should return all objects in a random order

Comment: is there any way to return all?

Comment: Also I don't understand what you mean by return all elements randomly. You mean the elements should be sorted in random order?

Comment: @lain yes but it shows duplicates as well I do not need duplicate

Comment: @dirkgroten yes sorted in random order without duplicate

Comment: Please add your model code

Comment: @Nerd that's not possible, `Model.objects.all().order_by('?')` will not show duplicates. Maybe you need to tell us how you see they are duplicates (which field are you looking at?)

Comment: @MarcellErasmus ok just a second

Comment: @dirkgroten I mean I have a 322 items in DB I should show user in random order but I have a pagination also when user click show more button It shows one object one more time. now it is clear?

Comment: @MarcellErasmus here you can have a look

Comment: @Nerd, nowhere in the code you're showing us is there any pagination (your ListAPIView doesn't have pagination). So please try to be complete when you ask a question. When you do `order_by('?')` and combine that with pagination, this won't work because every time a new page is fetched, the query is done again, so you will have chance of getting the same items in any page. You can't combine randomising and pagination, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Nerd why do you want the result to be randomised? You _could_ cache a seed value and use this to randomise a list of objects in a consistent order for each user

Comment: @dirkgroten sorry for some missing information, yes I have a pagination and I added to this question please look at updated version of question. According to question yes when pagination is done duplicated elements should not be shown is this possible to do?

Comment: @Nerd, no it's not possible because when you do a request, it can't "remember" what was sent in the previous one. So you would need to fetch all objects in random order once for a user (without pagination), remember that order somehow (save it) and then for each request paginate that list (instead of the original queryset). Better, just return all 322 objects without paginating. Or as Iain suggest, pseudo-randomise: keep a seed in a user's session and always use that for each request.

Comment: @dirkgroten in general is it ok to use `order_by('?')`

Comment: Yes. But as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) it might be very slow. Although it won't be slow with just 320 rows.

Comment: @dirkgroten yes for now it is only 320 but it is getting more and more everyday obeject is being added

Answer (score 1):

The approach I reach a similar goal is by annotating a hash of arbitrary fields.

The actual code looks like below.

**NOTE**: The `SHA1`(or other hash algo) function on Postgres requires extension `pgcrypto`

```py
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import SHA1, Concat


class ExampleModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    ExampleModel ViewSet
    """

    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer
    ordering_fields = ["random", "id"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = ExampleModel.objects.all()
        if (
            "ordering" in self.request.query_params
            and self.request.query_params["ordering"] == "random"
        ):
            random_seed = self.request.query_params.get("random_seed", "")
            qs = qs.annotate(
                random=SHA1(
                    Concat("name", Value(random_seed)),
                )
            ).order_by("random")
        return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, it stores a seed in the session so that a user gets the same randomised list of objects every time

```
class ItemsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    filter_backends = []

    def get_queryset(self):
        objects = list(Model.objects.all())
        seed = self.request.session.setdefault('seed', random.randint(1, 1000))
        random.seed(seed)
        result = random.sample(objects, len(objects))
        random.seed()  # Just for good measure
        return result
```

Comment: I used `sample` before I give this question then it threw this error `Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).` I used your answer but it is giving the same error

Comment: Try converting to a list first - updated the answer

Comment: I converted but I have a new error `'list' object has no attribute 'model'` and tried to customize your answer but it is still not working

Comment: This solution is not compatible with the `django_filters` backend, you'll have to set the filter_backends to an empty list if you don't mind not having it on this API

Comment: oops filter_backend is very important on this api without I cannot upload to the production unfortunately I will have to find another way